# Windows Error Reports

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-error-reporting

A Blizzard representative (Blizzard are the makers of World of Warcraft in case you didn't know) just suggested I post the MSInfo file for this PC on a tech support site becasue it's 'plagued' with Windows Error Reports, so I thought I'd try here.

This file is from April 15th.  I tried to create one today but it actually got stuck at 'Windows Error Reporting', so I gave up and posted the one from April 15th.

Here is a link to the April 15th file:

[MSInfo](http://www.filedropper.com/msinfo_1)

I'm hoping someone experienced might be able to shed some light on the matter.  In particular I would like to know the answer to this question: 'Is there anything in the MSInfo file that show there was an issue with the PC on April 15th and if so and I find that this issue still exists,  how might I solve it?'

Comment: What exactly is your question to us though?

Comment: well the first one is 'can i share the file and if so, how?' and the second one is 'is there an issue with the PC and what might I do to solve it?  Would  googling each of the errors be a good place to start or is this something better dealt with by an IT professional?

Comment: There are numerous file sharing websites that can be used.  You have not provided us with enough information, to tell, if you actually have an issue with your PC.

Comment: I understand that which is why I asked how to share the file.  Thanks for suggesting the use of a file sharing site.  Could you suggest one please?

Comment: No; I cannot suggest a file sharing website; That is decision you have to decide.

Comment: Nice customer support, Blizzard. But we're a Q&A site to help solve problems **that other future visitors might have as well**. Voting to close.

Comment: And what makes you think there's no chance at all of any future visitors having the same problem, if I might be so bold?

Comment: How would they find this question, George? Your question has no searchable details whatsoever.

Comment: Ok so I've just edited the title so that the question can be found by clicking 'Questions' and searching 'Windows Error Reports'.

Comment: Were you experiencing a particular problem with the game or your machine?

Comment: @MC10 Well when using Teamspeak the PC overheats so I can't use it and would like to.  Some people seem to think the PC should easily be able to handle Teamspeak so I wondered if there is an issue but I don't know.  Without Teamspeak there is no problem though as far as I know.

Comment: How would future visitors match *their* error report to your question?

Comment: @Arjan Why would they need to?  Could they not simply search 'Windows Error Reports' as I did?  Perhaps not the most efficient way of searching I guess.  Maybe I should make the title a specific error report.  What do you think?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson - There are literally hundreds of problems that generates windows error reports.  I still don't see a question that we can help you with.

Comment: And it seems the PC may have more than a few of those hundred problems.  Point taken though.  I need to ask a question about a specific error.  A particular question has sprung to mind which is to do with repeated reports that 3 addons need updating, which continue even after updating one of them.  Maybe I should ask a new question on this.  An answer has been given to the question impled by my having written 'In particular I would like to know if there is an issue with the PC and how I might solve it', which I plan to accept in due course if no answers appear and it's not closed.

Comment: You should ask a **new** question along the lines of "My PC is overheating when I do (xyz). Here are my PC specs. I have checked the following (xyz). What can I do to resolve this? As it stands you question is just too vague. The title doesn't say anything at all about your problem. Your question doesn't say anything at all about your problem. Your `msinfo` file is out of date ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok thanks.  I realise the msinfo file is out of date and as I mentioned in the OP, this is because it gets stuck at 'Windows Error Reporting', so how could I possibly provide an up to date one as things stand? Also, I have had problems with the PC overheating in the past when I played another game called TERA Rising and I asked a question about it then, which contains quite a bit of detail, although no WIndows Error Reports.  These reports may hopefully provide new useful information.

Comment: @DavidPosttill The question I mentioned is here: http://superuser.com/questions/767113/gaming-blew-fuse-and-causes-funny-smell-how-to-overcome.  I haven't yet accepted an answer as it isn't clear which, if any, is most useful, since although refraining from playing TERA has prevented further overheating (except possibly for one other occasion which happened immediately after making a change to the PC which I can't even remember at present), the specific nature and cause of the issue is still unknown to me.  As you can see, I am still investigating.  The question I linked details the PC spec.

Comment: @DavidPostill 
 
Oh and by the way, the question I linked in the comment above details the PC spec. All this said, I have some more new specific information on an issue that has arisen just now (a BSOD) after which the PC restarted and 2 specific files were named which are said to contain information on what caused the BSOD, so I have some information which may be worth including in a new question along the lines that you suggest. Thanks again. One area I am a little unclear on when using this site is where to draw the line with a given question.

Comment: @DavidPostill The nature of these issues is such that extended dialogue and the provision of numerous details of actions taken and various observation made seem necessary, along with the asking of a multitude of further questions, which doesn't seem conducive to fitting in with the instruction not to have extended conversations in comments. Should I have been attempting to engage in mulitple conversations with the various respondents who made comments? I don't know how to do this now that the link to start a chat conversation is no longer visible.

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe if I had clicked it when I saw it this problem wouldn't have occurred, but would other viewers be able to see the details of the initial conversation, which might be useful?  In the past I was told to edit the OP with any new information, but then criticised for asking new questions in the OP, thus making old answers to the original question and other questions asked in the OP prior to the latest edition obselete.  Is the best route to start a new post every time there is a new question, even though the new question is related to ithe old one, having followed on from it?

Comment: @DavidPostill Also, do you think it would be better to delete this question or accept the current answer, or is that a decision you don't think it's appropriate to give your opinion on?

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson  I would delete this one and make a new one (as specific as you can with the new information). Try to make the question completely stand alone (contains all the information).

Comment: @DavidPostill Well thanks.  Actually, I did say I was planning to accept Geruta's answer, so maybe I should keep my word on that, having thought about it.  After I finish this session I may not be online again now before Monday, when I plan to accept the answer if the question hasn't been closed and no answers appear which are even more useful.

Comment: @DavidPostill I do now have a current MSInfo file.  It did complete in 2 minutes or so, so I guess I was wrong to fly off the handle about your mention of the lack of current file.  However, since the original question was about the April 15th file and an answer was given which I said I'd accept, I felt I ought to keep my word on that, rather than moving the goalposts and breaking my word.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson Accepting an answer here is entirely up to you. As is creating a new question following my suggestion above "make a new one (as specific as you can with the new information). Try to make the question completely stand alone (contains all the information)"

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok thanks.  I'm holding fire on the new question about how I might change things so that using Teamspeak 3 doesn't cause the PC to overheat, which I may ask in the future, as I have found a possible solution myself which I might try first if I ever get back to trying to use Teamspeak.  I don't have a working mic at the moment so that's one reason I may not try to use Teamsspeak at present.  I ave jsut updated my drivers and vulnerable plugins though, so hopefully that should help the PC's performance.  Thank you all for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reviewed your log file and I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Unless you were expieriencing a specific issue, then there is no problem here. Likely the support rep saw this and was unfamiliar with Windows reporting, however I can only speculate.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll plan to wait a while before accepting to give others a chance to post an answer.  When using Teamspeak the PC overheats so I can't use it and would like to. Some people seem to think the PC should easily be able to handle Teamspeak so I wondered if there is an issue but I don't know. Without Teamspeak there is no problem though as far as I know.

Comment: When it overheats, does the PC just completely shutoff? If not, what happens specifically?

Comment: The screen froze and a loud noise like feedback came from the speakers.  I couldn't close WoW, access Task Manager or shut the PC down in the normal manner so had to switch off at the wall.

Comment: Are there any other applications that overheat or lockup the PC like this?

Comment: Other WoW addons may cause overheating, but not nearly as severely and the screen doesn't freeze.  It's just it seems the PC may be strained, so I don't use addons that have this effect.

Comment: Having considered your answer, I thought it worth my reiterating that the MSInfo file I linked is from April 15th, so whilst you have answered my question based on the information in that file, which is indeed what I asked for, and you saw nothing 'out of the ordinary' in it, it seems to me likely that it is out of the ordinary that 2 minutes or more is not currently sufficent time to create an MSInfo file due to what appears to be an enormous number of WIndows Error Reports.  I don't yet know how long it would take to create an MSInfo file, or indeed if it would ever complete as things stand.